# Drawing a bitmap using 2D DMA on STMF32F4

Tags: stm32, c, graphics

I'm trying to draw a bitmap using 2D DMA, so I have the address of the destination which is the front buffer, and then I read a line from the bitmap, blit it using the 2D DMA.. I get scanlines, and garbage image. Not sure where is the problem

```
void BSP_LCD_DrawBitmap(uint16_t layer,uint32_t X, uint32_t Y, const uint16_t *pBmp)
{
  uint32_t index = 0, width = 0, height = 0, bitpixel = 0;

  /* Get bitmap data address offset */
  index = 0;

  /* Read bitmap width */
  width = 240;

  /* Read bitmap height */
  height = 320;

    uint16_t address = LtdcHandler.LayerCfg[ActiveLayer].FBStartAdress ;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < height ; i++)
    {
       ConvertLineToRGB565( (uint16_t *)pBmp, (uint16_t *) address ,  width , CM_RGB565) ;
         address += (width*2) ;
         pBmp += (width*2) ;
    }   
}


static void ConvertLineToRGB565(void * pSrc, void * pDst, uint32_t xSize, uint32_t ColorMode)
{    
  /* Configure the DMA2D Mode, Color Mode and output offset */
  Dma2dHandler.Init.Mode         = DMA2D_M2M_PFC;
  Dma2dHandler.Init.ColorMode    = DMA2D_RGB565;
  Dma2dHandler.Init.OutputOffset = 0;     

  /* Foreground Configuration */
  Dma2dHandler.LayerCfg[1].AlphaMode = DMA2D_NO_MODIF_ALPHA;
  Dma2dHandler.LayerCfg[1].InputAlpha = 0xFF;
  Dma2dHandler.LayerCfg[1].InputColorMode = ColorMode;
  Dma2dHandler.LayerCfg[1].InputOffset = 0;

  Dma2dHandler.Instance = DMA2D; 

  /* DMA2D Initialization */
  if(HAL_DMA2D_Init(&Dma2dHandler) == HAL_OK) 
  {
    if(HAL_DMA2D_ConfigLayer(&Dma2dHandler, 1) == HAL_OK) 
    {
      if (HAL_DMA2D_Start(&Dma2dHandler, (uint16_t)pSrc, (uint16_t)pDst, xSize, 1) == HAL_OK)
      {
        /* Polling For DMA transfer */  
        HAL_DMA2D_PollForTransfer(&Dma2dHandler, 10);
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you do it without DMA?

Comment: How it should work with only looping through the height only ? I can do a nested loop with draw pixel and it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.
In case someone wants to do it

```
void BSP_LCD_DrawBitmap(uint16_t layer,uint32_t X, uint32_t Y, uint8_t *pBmp)
{

  uint32_t index = 0, width = 0, height = 0, bitpixel = 0;
  uint32_t address;
  uint32_t inputcolormode = 0;

  /* Get bitmap data address offset */
  index = 0;
  /* Read bitmap width */
  width = 240;

  /* Read bitmap height */
  height = 340;;

  /* Read bit/pixel */
  bitpixel = 2;

  /* Set Address */
  address = LtdcHandler.LayerCfg[ActiveLayer].FBStartAdress + (((BSP_LCD_GetXSize()*Y) + X)*(2));

    inputcolormode = CM_RGB565;

  /* bypass the bitmap header */
  pBmp += width*2;
   for(index=0; index < height; index++)
  {
  /* Pixel format conversion */
  ConvertLineToRGB565((uint32_t *)pBmp, (uint32_t *)address, width, inputcolormode);

  /* Increment the source and destination buffers */
  address+=  ((BSP_LCD_GetXSize())*2);
  pBmp += width*2;
  }
```